# how to increment session id variable after adding item into cart

Tags: php, session

i am working with a a cart item where user can add multiple item into the cart and delete the item from cart i am using session after adding one item i am increment id one by one on each add new item into cart the code is working is fine only problem in deleting when i am trying to delete the item from item tray its delete only one item here  is my code

```html
<?php
session_start();
if(!empty($_GET["action"])) {
switch($_GET["action"]) {
   case "add":
   if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
           $item_id_session = 1;
           $_SESSION['cart'] = array();

    }
    else
        {
            $count = count($_SESSION['cart']); 
            $item_id_session = $count++;
        }

            $item = array();
            $item['item_id_session']= $item_id_session ;
            $item['title']=$_REQUEST['title'];
            $item['length_m']  =$_REQUEST['length_m'];
            $item['length_md']=$_REQUEST['length_md'];
            $item['length_cm'] =$_REQUEST['length_cm'];
            $item['length_cmd']=$_REQUEST['length_cmd'];
            $item['width_m']=$_REQUEST['width_m'];
            $item['width_md']=$_REQUEST['width_md'];
            $item['width_cm']=$_REQUEST['width_cm'];
            $item['width_cmd']=$_REQUEST['width_cmd'];
            $item['height_m']=$_REQUEST['height_m'];
            $item['height_md']=$_REQUEST['height_md'];
            $item['height_cm']=$_REQUEST['height_cm'];
            $item['height_cmd']=$_REQUEST['height_cmd'];
            $item['weight']=$_REQUEST['weight'];
            $item['weightd']=$_REQUEST['weightd'];
            $item['quantity']=$_REQUEST['quantity'];
            $item['image']=$_FILES["image"]["name"];
            $target_dir = "profile_images/";
            $item['image']= "profile_images/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
            $imageFileType = pathinfo($item['image'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
         if($check !== false) {
         echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        //$uploadOk = 1;
         move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $item['image']);
         echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
         }
           $_SESSION['cart'][] = $item;
   break;
   case "remove":
     if(!empty($_SESSION["cart"])) {
      foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $k => $v) {
          if($_GET['item_id_session'] == $k)
            unset($_SESSION["cart"][$k]); 
            unset($_SESSION['cart'][$item_id_session]);      
          if(empty($_SESSION["cart"]))
            unset($_SESSION["cart"]);

      }
    }

   break;
     }
}
?>
```

here is my delete button code

```
    <a href="step3.php?action=remove&id=<?php echo $item["item_id_session"];?>"class="product-title">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash pull-right"></span>
    </a>
```

Comment: @Ryan Vincent  yes man its remain only one not increment that's why i want asking how i can increment this value after every new item added to the cart its will be increment

Comment: yes @Ryan Vincent adding is doing properly only problem is deleting because i don't have unique key that's why i am creating a unique key taking session id into a variable try to increment this variable

Comment: No i want to remove one item at a one time only its mean like shopping cart

Comment: Unless you are doing something elsewhere to reset the session then your code should add items to the cart. i.e.`var_dump($_SESSION, __FILE__.__LINE__);` immediately after `session_start();` and you will see the cart grow as you add items to it.

Comment: @Ryan Vincent   If am using var_dump($_SESSION['cart'], __FILE__.__LIME__); after session_start(); its perfect as u are saying but when  cart grow  but some how i want to remove a particular item from growing cart randomly then what should i do

Comment: You don't have error_reporting set for notices do you?`var_dump($_GET)`, There is no `item_id_session` index in there, There is an `id` index. i.e. `$_GET['id'] == $k`. In fact, you don't need the `foreach loop` but that is a different comment.

Comment: you mean to say i don't need foreach loop means i directly $_GET['id'] ;and delete the item

Comment: yes, just do: `if (isset$_SESSION["cart"][$_GET['id']]) {
            unset($_SESSION["cart"][$_GET['id']]); } `.  Instead of the `foreach loop ...`.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan Vincent i got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.while adding items to the cart you need to use `$item_id_session` as key.

```
 case "add":
    if (isset($_SESSION['cart']) && count($_SESSION['cart']) > 0) {
        $count = count($_SESSION['cart']);
        $item_id_session = $count+ 1;
    } else {

        $item_id_session = 1;
        $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
    }

                    $item = array();
                    $item['item_id_session']= $item_id_session ;
                    $item['title']=$_REQUEST['title'];
                    $item['length_m']  =$_REQUEST['length_m'];
                    $item['length_md']=$_REQUEST['length_md'];
                    $item['length_cm'] =$_REQUEST['length_cm'];
                    $item['length_cmd']=$_REQUEST['length_cmd'];
                    $item['width_m']=$_REQUEST['width_m'];
                    $item['width_md']=$_REQUEST['width_md'];
                    $item['width_cm']=$_REQUEST['width_cm'];
                    $item['width_cmd']=$_REQUEST['width_cmd'];
                    $item['height_m']=$_REQUEST['height_m'];
                    $item['height_md']=$_REQUEST['height_md'];
                    $item['height_cm']=$_REQUEST['height_cm'];
                    $item['height_cmd']=$_REQUEST['height_cmd'];
                    $item['weight']=$_REQUEST['weight'];
                    $item['weightd']=$_REQUEST['weightd'];
                    $item['quantity']=$_REQUEST['quantity'];
                    $item['image']=$_FILES["image"]["name"];
                    $target_dir = "profile_images/";
                    $item['image']= "profile_images/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
                    $imageFileType = pathinfo($item['image'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
                 if($check !== false) {
                 echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
                //$uploadOk = 1;
                 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $item['image']);
                 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
                 }
                   $_SESSION['cart'][$item_id_session] = $item;
           break;
           case "remove":
             if(!empty($_SESSION["cart"])) {
              foreach($_SESSION["cart"] as $k => $v) {
                  if($_GET['item_id_session'] == $k)
                    unset($_SESSION["cart"][$k]); 
              }
            }

           break;
```

Comment: i try your code  but its not working  also not adding multiple item into cart

Comment: yes its the unique one on that basis of i deleting the item

Comment: if i am doing $_SESSION['cart'][$item_id_session] = $item; then only one item is adding not multiple

Comment: i have edited my answer.i thing it is count increment problem.check now.

Comment: thanks value is increment but its deleting only one item from cart after deleting one another one is not deleting and thanks for your effort

Comment: i found solution exactly what i want only some changes needed   case "remove":
             if(!empty($_SESSION["cart"])) {
              unset($_SESSION["cart"][$_GET['id']]); 
            } but thanks without your support i can't handle this once again thanks.